# Google spreadsheets - sheet cells are not clickable

Tags: google-drive, google-sheets

A very strange issue...

I cannot click the cells with my mouse.
The mouse does move and operates.
It can even work the menu. But not the cells.

However, using the keyboard I do manage to manipulate and update the cells.

I work on Chrome 85.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Read only? Is it?

Comment: Is it a new spreadsheet or an old one?

Comment: @Tony - no. Or else I couldn't edit it using my keyboard.

Comment: @cup = an "old" one.

Comment: and if you close Sheets and then re-open it either in Chrome or another browser? Please [edit] your question with the result rather than add to the trail of comments.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Try using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled ... if that works, then it's very likely that your web broswer is using an extension that is causing the problem. If it still doesn't work add more details about your spreadsheet and your Google Sheets "environment" (how complex is your spreadsheet? does it has a script bounded to it? Do you have Google Sheets add-on "downloaded"? Are you the spreadsheet owner? Is your spreasheet shared? How is the persormance of your device (does it has enough free CPU/Disk Usage/RAM?)

Answer (score 1):

There have been reported problems with Chrome and mice but other browsers work fine (Firefox and Edge) and at least one other person has reported the same issue with no responses yet on Google Support.

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/72611516?hl=en

Suggest try your sheet on Firefox.